# Is there an R Function whrer i can combine multiple rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this table:

[image]

I want to combine the rows, so that the values off the variables are in one row from the same month.

Comment: The same month in general or the same month of the specific year?

Comment: Using `dplyr` you could do `mydata %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(across(-1, sum))`. If this doesn't work for you, please edit your question to make your example reproducible.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please read [ask] and give a [mre] in your question! `help(by)`

Comment: the same month of the specific year